# Return string of description given string of IDs (separated by commas)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, csv

I have one table A that has a column C and a lookup table (lookup) that provides a description given an ID.
Here the setup:

```
table A with column C values:

1,2,3
2,3,4

table lookup:
1, 'This'
2, 'is'
3, 'tricky'
4, 'SQL'
```

Provide a SQL (SQL Server 2005) statement that returns the following strings:

```
Input: 1,2,3    Output: 'This','Is','tricky'
Input: 2,3,4    Output: 'Is','tricky','SQL'
```

basically turning the string of IDs (from an input table A) into a string of descriptions

Answer (score 0):

The Samples that come with SQL Server 2005 include a CLR function called Split(). It's the best way of splitting comma-separated lists like this by far.

Suppose you have a table called `inputs`, with a column called `input`.

I forget what the particular outputs of dbo.Split() are... so work with me here. Let's call the fields `id` and `val`, where `id` tells us which entry it is in the list.

```
WITH
separated AS (
   SELECT i.input, s.id, s.val
   FROM 
       dbo.inputs AS i 
       CROSS APPLY 
       dbo.Split(i.input) AS s
)
, converted AS (
    SELECT s.input, s.id, m.string
    FROM 
        separated AS s
        JOIN
        dbo.mapping AS m
            ON m.number = CAST(s.val AS varchar(5))
)
SELECT c.input, (SELECT string + ' ' FROM converted AS c2 WHERE c2.input = c.input ORDER BY id FOR XML PATH('')) AS converted_string
FROM converted AS c
GROUP BY c.input;
```